# SSH tunnel with Docker PHP instance

Tags: networking, ssh, mysql, tunnel, docker

What I'm attempting to do is have MySQL discoverable by all docker instances and localhost on a remote server, but block MySQL from outside communication **except** a specific IP address (my home IP), or via a SSH tunnel.

I've recently discovered that in the `docker-compose.yml` file you can specify on the `ports` section the following:

`mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
        - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"`

However, this only means that it's available to the local host, and it cannot be used by any other interface.

You may ask "Well why don't you just SSH Tunnel in?" Well that is a solution sure for connecting to the docker instance on the remote directly, however, I'm not able to allow my **local** docker containers to use that tunneled port, specifically a PHP 7.1 container.

I've also tried changing IPTables to ignore all outside communication on port 3306 but for some reason it's still open.

I've got Putty set up to tunnel port 3306 on remote to port 10000 on local. MySQL Workbench can access it on 10000 like normal so the tunnel is doing it's job.

Basically my objective here is to allow an application on my localhost access the remote database, but not open up remote to effectively `bind 0.0.0.0`, as that is woefully insecure, and I understand that the best way to access MySQL is via tunnels directly to the box over SSH.

I've looked into having my local docker attempt to use the host IP, `expose_hosts` for docker-compose, all sorts. Banging my head against a wall here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that on your local machnine, you need to bind tunel to your docker network interface, not to localhost or 0.0.0.0. This will enable you to use this port from containers without opening it externaly.

At my computer, my docker interface (`docker0`) has address `172.17.0.1`, so I would try to bind to this address and then connect to this address from containter.